# Why I can set but I can't add a doc in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can:

```
  firestore
    .collection("messages")
    .doc(`${channel.currentChannel.id}`)
    .set(newMessage);
```

but I can't

```
  firestore
    .collection("messages")
    .doc(`${channel.currentChannel.id}`)
    .add(newMessage);
```

I get an error: `.add is not a function`
Why is this? Do I need to take a different approach for `chat` application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `.add is not a function` error because a Firebase [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) (the output of calling `.doc()`) does not have a `.add` method.

The `.add` method is available in a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference). The output of `.collection()` is a `CollectionReference` so you should call `.add` from there:

```js
firestore
  .collection(...)
  .add(...)
```

Comment: this means with firestore I need to create a new collection to use `add`. I'm wondering whether I need to create a new collection for `messages` or just add a `messages` collection on `currentChannel`

Comment: Using `.add()` automatically sets the document ID. If you want to control the value of the document ID, it might be better to use `.doc().set()`.